# Fetching from large lists while throttling is enabled

Tags: spquery

Here's the situation:

- I have a heavily customized web application built on top of MOSS 2007
- We're in the process of upgrading the application to SharePoint 2010
- QA has identified that a page which used to work fine in SP2007 now throws a SPQueryThrottleException, as it queries a large list.
- The list in question contains 52,000 items

At first sight, I thought "There are too much items being returned", so I've tried tweaking the query by setting the RowLimit and paging the results. This was to no avail: SharePoint still threw the SPQueryThrottleException.

I've looked at the query and added the fields in the `<Where />` clause to the indexed fields. According to various pages this should solve my problem, but it didn't. SharePoint still throws the exception.

I've tried using the `ContentIterator` to process the list, passing in an `SPList` and an `SPQuery`, including several options. Alas, I still get the SPQueryThrottleException.

I'm running out of options here. The AM Team has raised the throttling limit to 100,000 rows, but I don't like this solution as it's not future proof. Further raising the limit is an option (the farm is dedicated to this web application) but undesired. An alternative is setting `spList.EnableThrottling` to `false`, to me this feels like a hack.

The columns being queried are:

- A lookup column to a different list
- The "Created by" (Author) column

Can anyone provide me with some pointers on how I can get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Can the lookup column have multiple values? If not, then you should index it.

When building a query, SP looks for (and only uses) the first indexed column; if there isn't one and the list is large, it throws an SPQueryThrottledException.